# Can the principal values and directions (axes) of a rock's permeability anisotropy be determined on a single cylindrical core sample?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, tensor-calculus, porous-media

If a rock core (a right-cylinder of rock), as shown at the left of the image below, has bedding planes oriented arbitrarily with respect to the long axis of the core, how does one go about determining the principal values and directions of permeability anisotropy possessed by the core?

[image]

Typically, the rock core is placed within a rubber seal, creating a no flow boundary around its outer diameter (as depicted in the middle image of the figure above), and therefore flow can only occur across the cylinder's end faces.  Applying a constant head or pressure at one end face $(p_i)$ and another lesser pressure at the other $(p_o)$, one calculates a representative axial [permeability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permeability_(earth_sciences)#Description) using [Darcy's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darcy%27s_law):

$$\tag{1} k=\frac{q \mu L}{A \Delta p}$$

$k$ = permeability of the rock; $q$ = volumetric flow rate through the rock core; $\mu$ = fluid viscosity; $L$ = core length; $A$ = cross-sectional area normal to the macroscopic direction to fluid flow; $\Delta p = p_i - p_o$ = the pressure difference across the ends of the core.  The permeability value one would calculate in this scenario is invariant to the direction of flow (i.e. from end face 1 to end face 2 or vise versa).

A common assumption when using Eqn. 1 to assess the permeability of the rock is that its permeability value is a scalar quantity. But as qualitatively shown by the specific discharge vectors ($\vec v=q/A\cdot \hat n$) in the middle image of the figure above, [the permeability is actually a symmetric tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permeability_(earth_sciences)#Tensor_permeability) as a result of the orientation and shape of the asymmetric grains making up the rock.

One may write the permeability tensor as a 3 by 3 matrix in Cartesian coordinates as:
$$ \overline{\overline{k}}=\begin{bmatrix}k_{xx}&k_{xy}&k_{xz}\\k_{yx}&k_{yy}&k_{yz}\\k_{zx}&k_{zy}&k_{zz} \end{bmatrix}$$

when the principle axes of the permeability anisotropy do not coincide with the directions of the chosen coordinate system.

Thus the hypothetical flow shown in the middle image is governed by $k_{xx}, k_{yx}, k_{zx}$ if we take the pressure gradient to be co-linear with the $x$-axis.

Another (but less common) permeability measurement procedure is qualitatively shown at the right in the figure above.  In this procedure the rubber seal covers only a portion of the core's outer diameter and flow is directed across the core's diameter.  After a permeability measurement, the sleeve is rotated about the core's outer surface to a new angle and the measurement is repeated.  Using conformal mapping, the following equation was derived for calculating the transverse permeability

$$\tag{2} k = \frac{q\mu}{L\Delta p}G(\alpha)$$

where $G(\alpha)$ is a geometric correction factor account for the flow geometry of the fluid from inlet to outlet, and $\alpha$ is equal to $(\theta/2)$ ($\theta$ is defined as shown in the image).  However, a common assumption when using Eqn. 2 is that the rock's bedding planes are perpendicular to the long axis of the core, thus assuming there is no permeability contribution or flow component along the long axis of the core (the $x$-axis if assuming Cartesian coordinate system).

I understand that from linear algebra the principal values of the permeability tensor are given by the eigenvalues of the permeability tensor whereas the principal axes (directions) of the permeability anisotropy are given by the eigenvectors of the permeability tensor.

But here is my question, I can only determine one representative axial permeability value using the flow configuration as shown in the middle of the figure, and multiple representative transverse permeability values using the configuration shown at the right.  But how might I populate my 3 x 3 permeability matrix with these values (and in turn calculate the eigenvalues and eigenvectors)?

**Edit 1:** Cartesian coordinate system added to images.  Also responding to ChesterMiller's first question: "Suppose that the pressure gradient were only in the x direction. What would your equation give you for the components of the superficial velocity in the x, y, and z directions?"

Starting from the general 3D Darcy's law:
$$\tag{3} \vec v = -\frac{\overline{\overline{k}}}{\mu}\cdot \vec \nabla p$$

where $\vec v$ is the superficial velocity (previously referred to as 'specific discharge').  Expanding Eqn. 3:

$$\tag{4} \begin{bmatrix}v_x\\v_y\\v_z \end{bmatrix}=-\frac{1}{\mu}\begin{bmatrix}k_{xx}&k_{xy}&k_{xz}\\k_{yx}&k_{yy}&k_{yz}\\k_{zx}&k_{zy}&k_{zz} \end{bmatrix}\cdot\begin{bmatrix}\partial p/\partial x\\\partial p/\partial y\\\partial p/\partial z \end{bmatrix}$$

$v_x$ is the dot product of the first row of matrix $\overline{\overline{k}}$ with the pressure gradient vector $\vec \nabla p$:

$$\tag{5} v_x=-\mu^{-1} \left(k_{xx}\frac{\partial p}{\partial x}+k_{xy}\frac{\partial p}{\partial y}+k_{xz}\frac{\partial p}{\partial z} \right)$$

Similarly:
$$v_y=-\mu^{-1} \left(k_{yx}\frac{\partial p}{\partial x}+k_{yy}\frac{\partial p}{\partial y}+k_{yz}\frac{\partial p}{\partial z} \right)$$

$$v_z=-\mu^{-1} \left(k_{zx}\frac{\partial p}{\partial x}+k_{zy}\frac{\partial p}{\partial y}+k_{zz}\frac{\partial p}{\partial z} \right)$$

If $\vec \nabla p$ is only in the x direction, then $\partial p / \partial y = \partial p / \partial z = 0$, and thus the components of the superficial velocity are:

$$\tag{6} \begin{matrix}v_x=-\mu^{-1}k_{xx}\frac{\partial p}{\partial x}\\v_y=-\mu^{-1}k_{yx}\frac{\partial p}{\partial x}\\v_z=-\mu^{-1}k_{zx}\frac{\partial p}{\partial x} \end{matrix}$$

**Edit 2**: However, I think the superficial velocity components $v_y$ and $v_z$ as described in Eqn. 6 would be zero.  To facilitate my reasoning I constructed the image below:

[image]

To the far-left of the image (Fig. A) I show the laminated core, the selected coordinate system, and the directions of the principle permeabilities (which are not co-linear with selected coordinate system).  The minimum permeability direction is orthogonal to the maximum and intermediate permeability plane, i.e. orthogonal to the internal bedding planes.

Figure B is intended to illustrate the direction of macroscopic flow as would be calculated using Eqn. 6.  But, as Figure C is attempting to illustrate, at the macroscopic scale (at the [REV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representative_elementary_volume) or greater) the fluid cannot move any direction in the y or z direction because the core is bounded by an impermeable rubber seal.  Of course, I think the particles/molecules of fluid will travel some microscopic distance in the y or z direction as they must travel around rock grains to keep traveling downward, but the macroscopic direction of flow must be directed only along the x coordinate. Therefore, as Figure D illustrates, does it not stand to reason the resulting fluid motion is only in the x direction and the components of the superficial velocity would be?:

$$\tag{7} \begin{matrix}v_x=-\mu^{-1}k_{xx}\frac{\partial p}{\partial x}\\v_y=-\mu^{-1}k_{yx}\frac{\partial p}{\partial x}=0\\v_z=-\mu^{-1}k_{zx}\frac{\partial p}{\partial x}=0 \end{matrix}$$

Comment: Is the formation assumed to be transversely istropic, so that the permeability is the same in all directions parallel to the bedding planes?

Comment: @ChesterMiller I️ suppose I’m curious to know if it’s possible for the more general case (not assuming transversely isotropic), but also all ears with regards to this assumption

Comment: Suppose that the pressure gradient were only in the x direction.  What would your equation give you for the components of the superficial velocity in the x, y, and z directions?

Comment: @ChesterMiller please see edit 1 to question for answer

Comment: @ChesterMiller please see my edit 2 in response to your question.

Comment: In réponse to your edit, vy and vz can't be zero if dp/dx is the only pressure gradient.  So there must be some complicated flows present and pressure gradients in the y and z directions also if your boundary conditions are to be satisfied.  Do you know of the solution to the equations for an anisotropic slab (blocked in the y and z directions at their boundaries) with constant-pressure reservoirs at x = 0, L  to establish a gradient in the x-direction?

Comment: @ChesterMiller no I’m unaware of the solution you’re speaking of, what reference(s) should I️ look at? Also, how would you visualize the path a parcel of fluid would travel in the (initially fully saturated) homogeneous anisotropic core I️ have drawn, starting from top center?

Comment: I don't have the answers to these.  I'm confident I could model the flow and pressure variation, starting from a case where the sample is infinite in the z direction, short in the x direction (where the pressures are fixed at  x = 0 and x = L), and finite in the y direction (H<<L).  In this case, the pressure and the 3 velocity components would be functions of x and y (neglecting gravity).

Comment: @ChesterMiller so what are your thoughts, can an "inverse problem" be set up such that, with the one axial perm and with multiple transverse perm values, one can back out the principle values/directions?

Comment: I think that, using a more advanced version of the approach I outlined in my previous comment, you can get some of the permeability tensor components (those in the x-y plane, and the z component), but not all of them.  This would not be enough to establish the principal values and directions.  Plus, the sample would have to be very uniform, and it would have to be representative of a highly uniform formation.